# Can not append item to CollectionView

Tags: swift, collectionview

I am using a `CollectionView` inside a `UIViewController`, this `CollectionView` use PinterestLayout. I've already had 10 items now (1 is the "+" image and 9 gift images). When I click this `saveButton` to add one more `Gift`:

[image]

It doesn't load the "Torres" image.

[image]

Here is my code in the `saveButton` Action:

```
func saveButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        addViewIsShowed = false
        let caption = addView.addTextView.text
        let image = addView.addImageView.image!
        let gift = Gift(caption: caption, image: image.decompressedImage)
        // gifts.count is 10
        gifts.append(gift)
        // gifts.count is now 11
        addView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        collectionView.alpha = 1.0
        saveButton!.removeFromSuperview()
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

And here is CollectionViewDataSource methods:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return gifts.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GiftCollectionViewCell
   cell.gift = gifts[indexPath.item]
   return cell

}
```

Comment: What about your `UICollectionViewDataSource` code? Seems there's a problem there

Comment: I have added `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods.. Please check again. Thanks.

Comment: It seems ok. Are you sure those `UICollectionViewDataSource` are called after you add the new `Gift`?

Comment: Yes, I set debug at there and they are called.

Comment: When I change `gifts.append(gift)` to `gifts.insert(gift, atIndex: 1)`, It appends and shows torres image, but removes the image 9 on the `collectionView`.

Comment: Can you try to print the item height in this method? `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat`. It maybe returns 0 for your element

Comment: When I add new image, this function is not called.

Comment: this function is call when you do a reload data

Comment: I've already reload data from saveButton action.

Comment: Yes but not in a dispatch in your code example ;). So in this case it's normal that this function is not called

Comment: I've tried your code. But didn't work. When I add new image to the index == 1. It will show the new image, but the last origin image disappear.

Comment: Just to let you know that it is mandatory when you want to refresh a collectionView or TableView.After that, there is perhaps a problem with auto layout.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to refresh data in a collectionView you must do the reload data in the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
   collectionView.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: I need more code to help you on that. If you could put your UIViewController code it could be great. thanks

Comment: Ok. I've just added them. Please check again. Thanks.

Comment: As I said, When I change `gifts.append(gift)` to `gifts.insert(gift, atIndex: 1)`, It appends and shows torres image, but removes the image 9 on the collectionView. So reloadData should be called. I think the problem is the PinterestLayout.